# keystoneJS won't run default css

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, keystonejs

So I have created a pretty default keystoneJS project and the first error that appeared was that when ran locally the website's default css won't load.

It's looking for site.min.css but in the folder there is only site.scss

After I compiled the scss via sublime text 2 sublimeBuild and renamed the file to site.min.css (from site.css) it ran perfectly but what worries me is why does the default installation have this error.

Where should I change this? Is there an scss builder included so I have to change folder naming or is there some other issue?

My guess is that it has something to do with some step skipped. I remember the keystone installation asked me whether I wanted to use sass so I suppose everything should be ok.
Is the problem because I did not use grunt somehow?

I recall reading somewhere that this grunt tool has to be used instead of node when running a server and I see a Gruntfile in my folder but when installed grunt-cli the grunt just loads and terminates the server right after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything, `sass-middleware` is included and automatically generates CSS files from your SASS source files when they're requested.

The issue you were experiencing with site.min.css not being found was an error in the yeoman generator, from when the SASS support was added. The LESS middleware automatically compresses generated CSS when a request is made for a file ending in `.min.css`, but the SASS middleware doesn't do the same, so the request was 404'ing.

The problem with the yeoman generator has been fixed as of version 0.2.9, for existing projects the simple fix is to change your layout file so it refers to `site.css` instead of `site.min.css`.

Once you do that the middleware will automatically detect the presence of `site.scss` and generate an up-to-date version of `site.css` for you.

Comment: Ok, followup question. How do I make it work for .sass aswell and not just .scss? I tried editing gruntfile so that livereload checks for .sass aswell but nothing happened

Comment: Or should I ask this in another question?

Comment: I'm not sure, there may be options you can pass to the middleware to make it detect a different extension. Probably worth a separate question if you can't find the answer in the sass-middleware docs!